# Not working Joomla component at another Joomla installation

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.2, joomla3.3

I'm facing troubles with a self developed Joomla (backend) component. I developed it without any troubles and it is working fine on my development Joomla.

After installing the component on another Joomla system (different version) the component itself seems to work fine - but when selecting an entry to edit or to create a new one I'm receiving an error saying that he doesn't find the custom helper classes I developed.

I'm registering the classes as it is needed regarding the docs - and as already mentioned: it is working FINE with my development Joomla.

For testing I loaded the helpers "by hand" with `require_once()` - the error message itself is gone, but it doesn't work either. It doesn't even load the custom view but is showing the default listing.

Has anyone an idea what goes wrong?
The installation itself (via zip) was without any messages.

- Development Joomla version: 3.2.2
- Client Joomla version: 3.3.1

**Code excerpts for imports**

*controller.php*

```
class DhhcController extends JControllerLegacy {
  /* ... */
  public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false) {
    JLoader::register('DhhcHelper', JPATH_COMPONENT .'/helpers/dhhc.php');
    JLoader::register('LanguageHelper', JPATH_COMPONENT .'/helpers/language.php');

    // ...
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Can you please show the full code you're using the import the helper?

Comment: Is the file/folder declared in the extension's xml?

Comment: Those are the actual class names?  Also, I know this may sound crazy but you are totally positive the files are there?  I can't tell you how many times I've missed committing a new file.

Comment: @AdamB Actually yes. In the ``dhhc.xml`` in ``<extension/administration/files folder=admin>`` I'm including it with ``<folder>helpers</folder>``
@Elin Those are the class names and the files are at that place.

And as already mentioned: at my dev Joomla it is working fine ;-(...

Comment: Ya the point is if you forget to commit the files your dev will work fine but the new location won't.  Is the call to register returning true?  What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @Elin Both calls return ``NULL`` at both installations. When commenting out the ``JLoader::register()`` calls I'm receiving a fatal php error saying it is missing the classes (on the default controller). So that means that the helper classes are loaded on the default views. But after selecting an entry to edit or create a new one I receive the message that the helper class is missing. When including the file in the view class - nothing happens when an entry is selected or a new one will be created. I'm not redirected to that view but stay at the listing view.

Comment: It's a shot in the dark but maybe change JPATH_COMPONENT to something more specific e.d. JPATH_ROUTE . 'administrator/components/ '  .. it's really odd that it is getting a null if the files are in place.

Comment: ``JPATH_ROUTE`` is not defined...

Comment: In the meantime I updated my development version to the clients Joomla version. I removed the component from my development Joomla and reinstalled it with the same installation zip like the clients one. Same problem. I fixed the error message at clients Joomla but I'm experiencing problems with toolbar buttons. Those are not working. If I click them I stay on the same site... No JS error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was missing but still don't know why I needed it in that specific installation.

After cloning the client installation to my development machine I tried out several different things (deactivating different components...) but nothing helped me out. That specific Joomla installation from the client (with the same Joomla version!) didn't work with the component running on my Joomla dev installation on the same machine.

I debugged and debugged and found out what's preserving the component from working correctly after quiet a long time yet still don't know why exactly.

In **dhhc.php** (main file) I modified the file to that part:

```
<?php
// ...
require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT .'/helpers/dhhc.php');
require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT .'/helpers/language.php');

JLoader::register('DhhcHelper', JPATH_COMPONENT .'/helpers/dhhc.php');
JLoader::register('LanguageHelper', JPATH_COMPONENT .'/helpers/language.php');

$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Dhhc');
$controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('task'));
$controller->redirect();
```

Now it is working as expected.

I'm still wondering why my dev installation was including the **controller.php** on *every* site while at the client`s installation the **controller.php** was only included on the main controllers directly selected from the side toolbar.

Maybe someone can help this out ;-).